# Data Management Gateway connecting to MySQL

Tags: mysql, azure-data-factory

In my scenario, I do need to read data from a MySql database by Azure Data Factory. On a dedicated azure VM (Windows Server 2016), I have installed the Data Management Gateway 64bit. Before connecting to MySql I have to install the MySQL driver. Unfortunately there is no 64bit .NET MySql driver. So I decided to install the 32bit version of the Gateway instead. In this case the installer however terminated the installation, because of the 64 bit environment.

I am just wondering, if there is an option how to read data by Data Factory from the MySQL database, with a gateway installed on Azure VM.

Answer (score 0):

There is 64-bit MySQL driver. You can find the link of supported driver from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-onprem-mysql-connector